# Use of undeclared identifier in VC but its declared in the Custom UIImageView

Tags: uiviewcontroller, import, uiimageview, identifier

I'm having trouble with the use of an undeclared identifier. I have created a custom UIImageView and in it have declared a @property UILabel 'answeLbl'. I have imported the custom UIImageView.h file into my ViewController.h file but whenever i try to use the 'answerLbl' it comes up with the error 'use of undeclared identifier'. How do i stop this problem, i need to use this 'answerLbl' in my ViewController?

This is the ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NumberPadImageView.h"



@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

NumberPadImageView *numberKeyboard;

}
```

and then here is the custom uiiimageview => NumberPadImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NumberPadImageView : UIImageView {

UILabel *answerLbl;

UIButton *oneBtn;
UIButton *twoBtn;
UIButton *threeBtn;
UIButton *fourBtn;
UIButton *fiveBtn;
UIButton *sixBtn;
UIButton *sevenBtn;
UIButton *eightBtn;
UIButton *nineBtn;
UIButton *zeroBtn;

UIButton *backBtn;
UIButton *periodBtn;
UIButton *clearAnswerFieldBtn;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLbl;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
-(IBAction)backspace:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearAnswerLbl:(id)sender;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NumberPadImageView *imageView;
```

In viewDidLoad,

```
self.imageView = [[NumberPadImageView alloc]init];
```

Access by,

```
self.imageView.answerLbl
```

and declare answerLbl as property,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *answerLbl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been causing me so much trouble!

Comment: This only works when you are importing from ViewController.h and another custom VC e.g 'Custom1ViewController.h' how do you get it to work if you are trying to exchange data between say 2 custom VC's?